# ActionView::Template::Error (The asset "bootstrap.min.js" is not present in the asset pipeline.):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am coding a simple platform with Rails. I have deploy it in Heroku. Whe i test it local, it works, but in Heroku i have this error: `ActionView::Template::Error (The asset "bootstrap.min.js" is not present in the asset pipeline.):` :(

I have tried everything, but the error doesn't go. What do you think? What could i make? Thank you for your help!

PD:
My `assets.rb` file:

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

# Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'

# Add additional assets to the asset load path.
# Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Emoji.images_path
# Add Yarn node_modules folder to the asset load path.
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('node_modules')

# CSS
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( bootstrap.min.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( icons.scss )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( main.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( responsive.css )

# JS
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( app.js common.js home2.js )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( jquery-2.1.3.js )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( bootstrap.min.js )

# Fuentes
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
```

Answer (score 0):

I just add these lines to application.js:

```
//= require bootstrap.min
//= require jquery-2.1.3
//= require app
//= require common
//= require home2
```

and i delete the direct references to the files in the index.html.erb